What is the best way to generate sentences based on a simple description of possible sentences?
I would like to be able to generate sentences according to certain patterns or rules. What is the best way to do this? One way would be to write a parser/tokenizer that reads patterns and generates sentences, but that seems like reinventing the wheel, how do people do this? i.e.

the (cat|dog|fish) (eats|sees) the (bread|stone)

or more complex

(the (cat|dog|man)) (eats the (bread|pizza)|drink the (water|wine))
(I eat|You eat|((Bob|John|Mary) eats)) the (apple|pear|pizza)


Most modern NLP techniques don't make use of an explicit grammar, because pre-neural methods had little to no internal representation of the semantics of a word or phrase, which could lead to zero probabilities being assigned to rare sequences: not a huge problem for text generators, but a major issue when assessing the probabilities of sentences generated via, say, a phrase-to-phrase translation table. By operating in a real-valued vector space in which words with similar semantics are clustered, and defining our distributions over that space instead of over a discrete set of words, we bypass a lot of the issues that had previously required some complicated smoothing techniques if we didn't want to end up dividing by zero every time we saw a phrase that didn't appear in the training data.
So with all that in mind, I wouldn't recommend just defining a grammar and selecting (uniformly or otherwise) from the set of admissible sentences or admissible next-words. But a quick and dirty approach that might give you the best of both worlds would be to take a neural language model, use that to iteratively give you a distribution over the next word given the previous sequence of words, and then zero out the probabilities for any words that aren't permitted by your grammar, renormalize the vector, and select the next word from the resulting modified distribution.
You'll probably want to use a unidirectional LSTM (or stack thereof) for this. Bidirectional models and attention mechanisms would require that your modifications to the distribution be taken into account at earlier steps in the process, which would probably be doable, but you'd need to work out a lot of the math yourself, and it sounds like you're looking for something that more or less works out of the box. (This will be easier if you have a relatively simple grammar. LL(1) would be trivial, but once you start getting into the LR stuff, you'll probably need to store prior states and explore a search lattice over candidate sentence starts.)
Another option is to go in the opposite direction: use your grammar to generate partial sentences, use a neural language model to score their probabilities, and then at each step, prune the low-scoring candidates and expand the rest by another word.

Thanks. I understand what you mean. Basically I just want thousands of example sentences to create a data set for other purposes. I'll look into LSTM. Thanks!
